# Retrieve Activities that aren't being used in any Automations in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I'm cleaning unused Automations and Activities from a Marketing Cloud Account and I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the Activities that aren't being used in any Automation using SSJS. I have managed to write the following code but it is only retrieving Activities that are being used in Automations and I want to do the opposite.

```ssjs
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1");

    var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
    var currentDate = new Date();

    try {
        var automations = retrieveAllAutomations();

        for (var i = 0; i < automations.length; i++) {
            var automationObjectID = automations[i].ObjectID;
            var cols2 = ["Name", "ObjectID", "Description", "CustomerKey", "Sequence"];
            var filter2 = {
                Property: "Program.ObjectID",
                SimpleOperator: "equals",
                Value: automationObjectID
            };
            var activities = api.retrieve("Activity", cols2, filter2);
            for (var j = 0; j < activities.Results.length; j++) {
                var activity = activities.Results[j];
                Platform.Function.InsertData(
                    "DE_Name",
                    ["Automation_Name", "Automation_CustomerKey", "Activity_Name", "Activity_CustomerKey", "Description"],
                    [
                        automations[i].Name,
                        automations[i].CustomerKey,
                        activity.Name,
                        activity.CustomerKey,
                        activity.Description
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        Write(Stringify(err));
    }

    function retrieveAllAutomations() {
        var out = [],
            moreData = true,
            reqID = data = null;

        var cols = [
            "Name",
            "Description",
            "CustomerKey",
            "IsActive",
            "CreatedDate",
            "ModifiedDate",
            "PartnerAPIObjectTypeID",
            "Status",
            "ProgramID",
            "CategoryID",
            "LastRunTime",
            "ScheduledTime",
            "LastSaveDate",
            "ModifiedBy",
            "LastSavedBy",
            "CreatedBy",
            "AutomationType",
            "RecurrenceID"
        ];

        var filter = {
            Property: 'Status',
            SimpleOperator: 'IN',
            Value: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
        };

        while (moreData) {
            moreData = false;

            if (reqID == null) {
                data = api.retrieve("Automation", cols, filter);
            } else {
                data = api.getNextBatch("Automation", reqID);
            }

            if (data != null) {
                moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
                reqID = data.RequestID;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Results.length; i++) {
                    out.push(data.Results[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        return out;
    }
</script>
```